# integration yadcf and datatables jquery

Tags: jquery, datatables, yadcf

I am trying to hide some columns, and to integrate newly added ydcf filtering with my existing script..here is my script that isn't working:

```
    <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/resources/css/jquery-ui.1.9.0.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/resources/css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="/resources/css/jquery.dataTables_themeroller.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="/resources/css/select2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="/resources/css/jquery.dataTables.yadcf.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="/resources/css/shCore.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="/resources/css/shThemeDefault.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="/resources/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="/resources/js/select2.js"></script>
<script src="/resources/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="/resources/js/jquery.dataTables.yadcf.js"></script>
@*<script src="/resources/js/dom_source_select2_example.js"></script>*@
<script type="text/javascript" src="/resources/js/shCore.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/resources/js/shBrushJScript.js">   </script>
 <script>

    var oTable;


    $(document).ready(function () {
        'use strict';

        oTable = $('#example1').dataTable({
            "bJQueryUI": true,
            "bStateSave": true,
            autoFill: true,
            colReorder: true,
            "iDisplayLength": 1000,
            "columnDefs": [

           {
               "targets": [0],
               "visible": false,
               searchable: false
           }
            ]
        }).yadcf([
            { column_number: 0, filter_type: "multi_select", select_type: 'select2' },
            { column_number: 1, filter_type: "range_number_slider" },
            { column_number: 2, select_type: 'select2', select_type_options: { width: '150px', minimumResultsForSearch: -1 } },
            { column_number: 3, filter_type: "text", text_data_delimiter: ",", exclude: true },
            { column_number: 4, select_type: 'select2', select_type_options: { width: '150px', placeholder: 'Select tag', allowClear: true }, column_data_type: "html", html_data_type: "text", filter_reset_button_text: false }]);

        SyntaxHighlighter.all();
    });
</script>
```

So, I want to add pdf, excel and other buttons, as well as to hide some columns and etc.
Thanks.

EDIT:

Here is my whole View:

```
@using Common
@using MVC.Controllers
@using DataAccess
@model IEnumerable<DataAccess.AdeccoView>
@{
Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>
<title>TestView</title>
<link href="/resources/css/jquery-ui.1.9.0.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/resources/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="/resources/css/select2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/resources/css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="/resources/css/jquery.dataTables_themeroller.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="/resources/css/jquery.dataTables.yadcf.css" rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css"/>
<link href="/resources/css/shCore.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="/resources/css/shThemeDefault.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

<script   src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="/resources/js/select2.js"></script>
<script src="/resources/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="/resources/js/jquery.dataTables.yadcf.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/resources/js/shCore.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/resources/js/shBrushJScript.js">  </script>

</head>
<body>
       <script>
        var oTable;
        $(document).ready(function () {
        'use strict';

    //----------------------------------------------
    //note that this is the old yadcf API for init the filters 
    //new init function should be used when working with new Datatable  (capital "D" API)
    //for new init function see: http://yadcf- showcase.appspot.com/DOM_Ajax_Multiple_1.10.html
    //----------------------------------------------

      oTable = $('#example1').dataTable({
        "bJQueryUI": true,
        "bStateSave": true,
        "columnDefs": [
        {
            "targets": [ 5 ],
            "visible": false,
            "searchable": false
        }]
    }).yadcf([
        //{
        //column_number: 0,
        //filter_type: "multi_select",
        //select_type: 'select2'
        //},
    {
        column_number: 1,
        filter_type: "range_number_slider"
    }, {
        column_number: 2,
        select_type: 'select2',
        select_type_options: {
            width: '150px',
            minimumResultsForSearch: -1 // remove search box
        }
    }, {
        column_number: 3,
        filter_type: "text",
        text_data_delimiter: ",",
        exclude: true
    }, {
        column_number: 4,
        select_type: 'select2',
        select_type_options: {
            width: '150px',
            placeholder: 'Select tag',
    allowClear: true  // show 'x' (remove) next to selection inside the select itself
},
    column_data_type: "html",
html_data_type: "text",
filter_reset_button_text: false // hide yadcf reset button
}]);

SyntaxHighlighter.all();
});

</script>





<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" id="example1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ViewID)</th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Date)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Client.ClientName)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.EventType)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Employee.NameSurname)
            </th>
            <th>
                Options
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ViewID)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Date)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Client.ClientName)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.EventType)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Employee.NameSurname)
            </th>
            <th>
                Options
            </th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ViewID)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ShortDate)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Client.ClientName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EventType.Event)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Employee1.NameSurname)
                </td>
                <td>

                    <button type="button" data-id="@item.ViewID" class="editView">Edit</button>
                    @{
            bool isUser = (Session["user"] as Employee).PrivID == 1;
            if (isUser)
            {
                <button type="button" data-id="@item.ViewID"  class="deleteView">Delete</button>
            }

                    }
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: except the fact that you can't filter column that is marked `searchable: false` your code looks fine, provide some additional info about your error what exactly the problem?

Comment: if you have some error that is being **caused by yadcf** post the error (from browser dev tools console) otherwise I can't help

Comment: There isn't a specific error, just my code isnt working. For example I want to hide column, but it wont.